# Xcode 8.1 : No options for update frames on changing constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints, scrollview

I've done the following steps:

1. Added scrollview to main view.
2. Added constraints 0,0,0,0 top, left,bottom, right to scrollview.
   RESULT: Scrollview updates frames
3. Added button to scrollview
4. and added constraints 0,0,0,0 top, left,bottom,right and even width,height

RESULT : Can't update frame of UIButton

I don't why I can't update frame after applying constraint to button view .

error says: has ambiguous scrollable height
[image]

if I add other views or change anything like give height constraint to scrollview , it becomes red with the same error.

Any suggestion.

Comment: Scrollview need height and width also, you can try add it with `add missing constraint` so you will know which one is missing

Comment: There are many tutorials regarding UIScrollView.if u are working first time just check them. For example https://www.appcoda.com/tag/uiscrollview/

Answer (score 9):

Xcode 8.1 have new Update Frames button.

[image]

Comment: i don't see this button

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `ContentView` in `UIScrollView` and add constraint on that `UIView` from top,left,bottom and right.

Now inside that `UIView` you need to add that button view, then it will work.